# how to connect application running on localhost from docker container

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to connect the application (which is not running on docker)[image]

- i am trying to run this docker image with the help of docker compose.
- i am using host network mode connecting external services on
  **host.docker.internal** on port 7497
- i am trying to call from the docker container from the python code
  this docker is not having port config

  ```
   services:
     ibkr-bot-eminisp500:
       container_name: ibkr-bot-eminisp500
       image: |my-image|
       network_mode: host
       extra_hosts:
         - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
       environment:
         - IBKR_CLIENT_URL_KEY= "host.docker.internal"
         - IBKR_PORT_KEY=7497
  ```

but i am getting following error. what i am missing

```
| API connection failed: gaierror(-2, 'Name or service not known')
ibkr-bot-eminisp500    | Traceback (most recent call last):
ibkr-bot-eminisp500    |   File "/usr/bin/src/app/main.py", line 8, in <module>
ibkr-bot-eminisp500    |     ibkrBot = IBKRBot()
```

Answer (score 0):

Combining `host.docker.internal` with `network_mode: host` doesn't make any sense.

If you're running under Linux, then when using `network_mode: host` your container is running your host's main network environment. Drop the `extra_hosts` section from your config because it isn't doing you any good. You can connect to a service on your host using any ip address from any host interface, including `127.0.0.1`.

If you are running on anything other than Linux, then `network_mode: host` is probably never useful (because the Docker "host" is actually a virtual machine running on top of your primary operating system). In this case, drop `network_mode: host` from your config, and connect using `host.docker.internal`.